# VB.NET Track COM RCW error

Tags: vb.net, com, rcw

I have a really big project that I can not easily strip down.

When the application is being closed, I get the error

```
"InvalidComObjectException: A COM object that has been disconnected from the RCW can not be used."
```

Details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException has occured.
  HResult=-2146233049
  Message=A COM object that has been disconnected from its RCW can not be used.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.StubRegisterRCW(Object pThis)
  InnerException:
```

Unfortunately I can not see what COM object this is about.
Does anybody know how I can find that out? Unfortunately I can't read ASM to analyze the disassembly.

Comment: Is it possible to get another error related to this one? If an unspecified COM fails can you find out which one it is by other errors? Can you duplicate this behavior in Visual Studio?

Comment: It happens each time. I am not sure what you mean by "another error related to this one". Everything works fine, but I get this error.

Comment: Did you add any ActiveX controls. Right click Toolbox, then choose Items. Then click the COM tab and see if anything is checked, this would be best to check.

Comment: have you got any code running on the handler "Me.FormClosing" or "Me.FormClosed"

Comment: Do you happen to call Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject anywhere in your code (or any code you reference directly or indirectly)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some steps you could try and since you haven't posted any code I will try to enumerate some of the most common key factors...

First, there is no order when disposing objects. If a close/dispose/finalize action is invoked, **object C** might be disposed before **object A** and if some object is still alive it might try to access an already disposed object.

Second, beware of events. It's very common to get errors about accessing a disposed object originated from an event call.

Third, do not dispose objects inside an event scope nor destructors. Create your own method to free your object(s).

Since you don't know which COM object is the culprit, I suggest you look for the ones that you do close, dispose, disconnect, etc...

You might want to read [this blog](http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/wrappers-unwrapped/) in order to better understand how RCW's work and also to help you with your problem.

**Edit**:

After reading your comment, I felt I should add two possible causes:

- If after removing `Microsoft.VisualBasic runtime methods` you've solved your problem, then I suspect that inside one, or more, of those methods you have incremented the count of a reference to one, or more,  of your COM(s) and did not release properly.
  Be sure to `ReleaseComObject` checking the reference count until it's 0 and then set it to **nothing**(VB) or **null**(C#) and let the Garbage Collector do the rest.
- The other option is that one of those methods tried to access an already disposed reference to a COM object, resulting in a RCW error, since is no longer callable.

As a final comment, after releasing the COM object always set it to **nothing** or **null**, this will release the reference to the variable and you can always check it's availability anywhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem some other way... Not sure what the real cause was, but I removed all Microsoft.VisualBasic runtime methods, and suddenly the RCW error was gone. Else I would have tracked down the error as you suggested (removing controls one by one).